# Calculate the Error of Kmeans Clustering

Tags: opencv

How do we calculate error of k-means clustering problem ? 
I have done the k-means clustering. Now I am looking for calculation of error of K-means Clustering. How could i do that ? please help me.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [docs for kmeans](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/clustering.html#double%20kmeans%28InputArray%20data,%20int%20K,%20InputOutputArray%20bestLabels,%20TermCriteria%20criteria,%20int%20attempts,%20int%20flags,%20OutputArray%20centers%29),

> The function returns the compactness measure